# Changing units of measurement in a simple regression model

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, econometrics, regression-coefficients

Assume a simple regression model, $y = \beta_0 + x\beta_1 + u$. I decide to change the units of measurement for the explanatory variable and the response variable. Do the $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ parameters change as well?

I assume that the $\beta$ parameters will stay constant.

Does anyone know for sure?

How does it change the value of $R^2$?

Comment: How do change the measurement? In general the parameters change in the same way you change the variables

Answer (score 3):

Consider the simple regression model $y=\beta_0 + \beta_1x + u$ where $u \sim N(0,1)$ is iid.

## Rescaling $x$ only

- $\beta_1$ *will* change if you change the units of $x$ only. For
  example, if $x$ is the dose of a drug in mg. You might want to
  express the $\beta_1$ as the unit change in $y$ for a 50mg change in
  dose. Then you multiply $x*50$ but that's just the same thing as
  dividing $\beta_1$ by 50 (vice versa). So scaling the $x$ is the same as scaling the estimated $\beta_1$ correspondingly. The interpretation of $\beta_1$ changes only because you're dealing with different units. The degree (and statistical significance) of the association with $y$ will not change.
- You'll notice if you do a substitution that rescaling $x$ in no way affects $\beta_0$.
- The $R^2$ metric will not be affected either. It's a measure of fit. It doesn't matter what units your variables are in.

## Rescaling $x$ and $y$ equivalently

- This shouldn't change the $\beta_1$ or $R^2$ but it will rescale the $\beta_0$ correspondingly.

## Examples in R

Lets just go through an example in R.

```
# generate x and y with beta_1=4 and beta_0=10 and i.i.d standard normal errors
set.seed(1)
x<-rnorm(100,30,10)
y<-10+4*x+rnorm(100,0,1)

# estimate basic regression
summary(lm(y~x))
```

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.8768 -0.6138 -0.1395  0.5394  2.3462 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  9.96549    0.34847    28.6   <2e-16 ***
x            3.99989    0.01077   371.3   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9628 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9993,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9993 
F-statistic: 1.379e+05 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Now let's rescale only x.

```
# Now rescale only x
# notice the coefficient and standard errors scale correspondingly
# but the R^2 and t-statistics/p-values do not.
x_rescale<-x/100
summary(lm(y~x_rescale))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x_rescale)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.8768 -0.6138 -0.1395  0.5394  2.3462 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   9.9655     0.3485    28.6   <2e-16 ***
x_rescale   399.9894     1.0773   371.3   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9628 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9993,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9993 
F-statistic: 1.379e+05 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Now we'll rescale both x and y

```
# now rescale y and run a regression where both x and y are rescaled.
y_rescale<-y/100
summary(lm(y_rescale~x_rescale))

Call:
lm(formula = y_rescale ~ x_rescale)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.018768 -0.006138 -0.001395  0.005394  0.023462 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.099655   0.003485    28.6   <2e-16 ***
x_rescale   3.999894   0.010773   371.3   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.009628 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9993,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9993 
F-statistic: 1.379e+05 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```